# sqlplus Setting the exit code of a script

Tags: sqlplus

How can I set the exit code of a script?

The following doesn't seem to work

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 5

DECLARE
     retCode number := 0;

BEGIN
     retCode := 30; 
END;
/
EXIT :retCode ;
```

Gives the usage for EXIT with an exit code of 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
var retCode number
exec :retCode := 30;
exit :retCode
```

(See http://www.orafaq.com/forum/mv/msg/80574/233106/0/#msg_233106)

Bottom line is that *retCode* must be a variable defined in SQL*PLUS's scope. Your **DECLARE** is inside a code block, and SQL*PLUS can't see into it.